# Is the conjunction of asymptotic Goldbach's and Elliott-Halberstam conjectures known to imply the twin prime conjecture?

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

I may have a proof that, assuming every large enough even integer is the sum of two primes as well as Elliott-Halberstam conjecture, then there are infinitely many twin primes.

Is such a result already known? If yes, could someone provide me a reference? Otherwise, would it be an interesting result?

Comment: why do you think they are related

Comment: Let me remind you this: http://www.les-mathematiques.net/phorum/read.php?5,1758830

Comment: No idea of what you want to say. Is your goal to not look at the recent proof of the infinitely many prime pairs $p,p+2k, k \le K=10^{60}$ ? They claim $K$ can be improved under  Elliott-Halberstam so...

Comment: Polymath8b proved that under EH conjecture, there are infinitely many $n$ such that $n-r$ and $n+r$ are primes with $r$ not exceeding $6$ (take the half sum of pairs of primes at most $12$ apart from each other). Now under asymptotic Goldbach for every large enough $n$ the set $G(n):=\{r>0,(n-r,n+r)\in\mathbb{P}^{2}\}$ is non-empty. Let $r_{0}(n)$ be the infimum of $G(n)$ and say $n$ is $k$-hexaedral if $r_{0}(n)=k$ and divides $6$...tbc

Comment: Say $n$ is conservative if $r_{0}(n)$ is the gcd of elements of $G(n)$ less than $n-p_{\pi(\sqrt{2n-3})}$. If as I suggest it in the link above $n$ is conservative iff $n$ is $k$-hexaedral for some divisor $k$ of $6$, then there should exist infinitely many conservative integers. From Dirichlet's prime number theorem in arithmetic progressions, the set of $k$-hexaedral integers for a given $k$ has positive density among the set of conservative integers...tbc

Comment: Hence there are infinitely many $1$-hexaedral integers, hence infinitely many twin primes.

Comment: No, I don't think this result is known. Yes, it would be interesting. But I don't follow your sketch proof. Why are there infinitely many conservative integers? How are you using Dirichlet's theorem?

Comment: Even if this implication is true, we would need two conjectures for the twin prime conjecture. I do not think that the two conjectures have more evidence to be true than the twin prime conjecture. So, it is well possible that someone proved this implication but did not consider it to be worth to be published.

Comment: If $n$ is conservative, the finite sequence $n\odot r_{i}(n)$ with $\odot\in\{+,-\}$ and $r_{i}(n)$ being the sequence of elements of $G(n)$ in increasing order is of the form $n\odot k_{i}r_{0}(n)$ with $(k_{i})_{i}$ an increasing sequence of positive integers. $n$ and $r_{0}(n)$ are coprime, hence Dirichlet's theorem applies.